# In a Lie group, is it true that $i_*v^L=-v^R$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

If $G$ is a Lie group and $v\in T_eG$, then I want to show that $$i_*v^L=-v^R$$ where $i$ is the inversion map $G\to G: g\mapsto g^{-1}$ and $v^L$ and $v^R$ are the left and right invariant vector fields, respectively, extending $v$.

I already have:

$$(i_*)_g(v^L)_g=(i_*)_g((L_g)_*)_ev=((R_{g^{-1}})_*)_e(i_*)_e v=-(v^R)_{g^{-1}}$$

where I have used that $i(L_g(h))=R_{g^{-1}}(i(h))$. Is it then true that $(v^R)_{g^{-1}}=(v^R)_g$?

Any help would be welcome!

Comment: Please edit to include exactly what you have done.

Comment: I have included extra details

Comment: Your proof is fine. Your last question makes no sense! You can only compare tangent vectors at the same point. But perhaps you should write down more precisely what it is that you need to show!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if $m\colon G\times G\to G$ is the multiplication and $\iota\colon G\to G$ is the inversion, differentiating $$m(g,\iota(g)) = e$$relative to $g$ at $v\in T_gG$ gives us that $${\rm d}(R_{g^{-1}})_g(v) + {\rm d}(L_g)_{g^{-1}}({\rm d}\iota_g(v)) = 0\implies {\rm d}\iota_g(v) = - {\rm d}(L_g)_{g^{-1}}^{-1}\circ {\rm d}(R_{g^{-1}})_g(v).$$Now, we recall that whenever $X\in T_eG$, we set $X^L_g = {\rm d}(L_g)_e(X)$, as well as $X^R_g = {\rm d}(R_g)_e(X)$.

We usually write $X^L_g = gX$, $X^R_g = Xg$, and ${\rm d}\iota_g(v) = -g^{-1}vg^{-1}$, using "multiplication" notation for derivatives of left and right translations (the base points work out). With this in place, we have that $${\rm d}\iota_g(X^L_g) = -g^{-1}gXg^{-1} = -Xg^{-1} = - X^R_{g^{-1}} $$In words: the derivative of the inversion map at the point $g\in G$ sends the tangent vector $X^L_g \in T_gG$ to the tangent vector $-X^R_{g^{-1}} \in T_{g^{-1}}G$.